# What's the problem with my TRIGGER sql statement - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to keep track of records from a particular table before they get deleted. I'm running an SQL TRIGGER statement with MySQL and it runs successfully, but my deleted rows aren't getting inserted into the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment` LIKE `tblvendorpayment`;

ALTER TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment`
MODIFY COLUMN `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment` DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment`
ADD COLUMN `history_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment`
ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`);

ALTER TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment`
MODIFY `history_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER `delete_tblvendorpayment`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `delete_tblvendorpayment` BEFORE DELETE on `tblvendorpayment`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO history_tblvendorpayment (id, created_by,
    vendor_id, amount_payable,
    amount_payed, description,
    depositor_name, gl_code_credit,
    gl_code_debit, txn_date,
    pay_date, ref_id,
    bank, currency,
    date, md_approval,
    status, sage_status,
    memo_id)  
    VALUES (
        OLD.id, OLD.created_by,
        OLD.vendor_id, OLD.amount_payable,
        OLD.amount_payed, OLD.description,
        OLD.depositor_name, OLD.gl_code_credit,
        OLD.gl_code_debit, OLD.txn_date,
        OLD.pay_date, OLD.ref_id,
        OLD.bank, OLD.currency,
        OLD.date, OLD.md_approval,
        OLD.status, OLD.sage_status,
        OLD.memo_id
    );END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The code looks perfectly fine - the issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then Although your code looks fine, but this is shorter

```
CREATE TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment` LIKE `tblvendorpayment`;

ALTER TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment`
MODIFY COLUMN `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE `history_tblvendorpayment` DROP PRIMARY KEY;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `delete_tblvendorpayment` BEFORE DELETE on `tblvendorpayment`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO history_tblvendorpayment
    SELECT *
    FROM tblvendorpayment
    WHERE id = OLD.id;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it was something else